# Google analytics migration to firebase

Tags: google-analytics, migration, firebase-analytics

I have a project which has google analytics and we have important data in GA which we don't want to loose is there any possible way while migrating to FireBase Analytics we can have this data there as well.

What I have tried so far is we can export data from GA in JSON format using Big Query, is there any way we can import this data to FireBase analytics using Big Query or is there a way I can link my GA account to firebase project and data migration will be done automatically?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you asking in context of mobile apps?

Comment: @michalbrz Yes I have android and iOS apps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, the answer is no: there is no way to import old data to Firebase. That's why during the transition period (from GA to Firebase) it's recommended to use both SDKs or Google Tag Manager in order to log everything to both GA and Firebase. Then when you have built enough historical data in Firebase you can switch to it.

If you need both sets of data (Firebase and GA) you can export your GA analytics data to BigQuery, export Firebase data to BigQuery and then combine them and process them outside of Firebase, for example using Data Studio.